# tableView.setContentOffset(_, animated:) do not work after beginUpdates()

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, offset

After using

```
beginUpdates()
endUpdates()
```

This method ->

```
tableView.setContentOffset(_, animated:) // do not work
```

Do not work after calling that 2 methods (even if I use timer), but works without them!
Any ideas why?

setContentOffset works only if I swipe tableView manually after `beginUpdates() + endUpdates()` and BEFORE `setContentOffset` is being called.

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath` works fine though but I need only `setContentOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.setContentOffset(_, animated:)` works now when I calling with a dispatch to the main thread! So,

```
beginUpdates()
endUpdates()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -offset), animated: true)
}
```

This way works.